# PHPUnit Strict Mode - setUp() - Coverage

Tags: php, phpunit

I currently started using the `strict`-Mode in PHPUnit, when I came across a Problem with the code-coverage:

If I use the `setUp`-method to create a new instance of a my class the `__constructor`-method is listed in the code-coverage as covered when i run the tests.

This is my test-setup:

`phpunit.config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://schema.phpunit.de/4.5/phpunit.xsd"
    bootstrap="../vendor/autoload.php"
    backupGlobals="false"
    backupStaticAttributes="false"
    colors="true"
    verbose="true"    
    beStrictAboutOutputDuringTests="true"
    beStrictAboutTestSize="true"
    beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="true"
    beStrictAboutTodoAnnotatedTests="true"

    checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="true"
    processIsolation="false"
>
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="FooTests">
        <directory suffix="Test.php">../tests</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>
<filter>
    <whitelist>
        <directory suffix=".php">../src</directory>
    </whitelist>
</filter>
<logging>
    <log type="coverage-html" target="coverage/" higlight="true" showUncoveredFiles="true"></log>    
</logging>
```

Foo.php

```
class Foo
{

    protected $_bar;

    public function __construct($bar)
    {
        $this->_bar=$bar;             //Line 10
    }                                 //Line 11

    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->_bar;
    }

    public function getBar2()
    {
        return $this->_bar;
    }

}
```

and the Test: FooTest.php

```
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{

    protected $_foo;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->_foo=new Foo(10);
    }

    public function testGetBar()
    {
        $this->assertSame(10, $this->_foo->getBar());
    }

    /**
     * @covers Foo::getBar2
     */
    public function testGetBar2()
    {
        $this->assertSame(10, $this->_foo->getBar2());
    }

}
```

If I run the tests I get this result:

```
PHPUnit 4.5.0 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Configuration read from C:\xampp\htdocs\unittest\build\phpunit.config.xml

.R

Time: 88 ms, Memory: 3.50Mb

There was 1 risky test:
1) FooTest::testGetBar2
This test executed code that is not listed as code to be covered or used:
- C:\xampp\htdocs\unittest\src\Foo.php:10
- C:\xampp\htdocs\unittest\src\Foo.php:11

OK, but incomplete, skipped, or risky tests!
Tests: 2, Assertions: 2, Risky: 1.

Generating code coverage report in HTML format ... done
```

As soon as I specify the `@covers` on the test the problem appears.

Is this expected behavior?

Some things I tried:

- Changing `checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode` to `false` obviously works, but I want to use this feature...
- Using `processIsolation="true"` works too. I don't know why?
- Adding `@covers` or `@uses` to `setUp()` doesn't work
- Adding `@covers` that the `setUp()` uses  to the test does work, but the test doesn't actually cover the code. (If the tests get more complex, this seems to be a lot of writing...)
- Different `phpunit`-Version: I tried this with `4.3` and `4.5` with same results
- Different PHP-Setup: I tried this on a Win8 with XAMPP and a LinuxMint - same results

Is there a way to remove the `setUp()` code from the code-coverage and using `@covers` on tests with methods they actually test?

Edit: This also affects inheritance. So if `Bar` extends `Foo`, and passes arguments on to `Foo::__construct` that will be on the code-coverage too - which makes writing the `@covers` for the `__construct` a pain in the a**...

Additional info:

```
PHP 5.6.3 (cli) (built: Nov 12 2014 17:18:08)
Copyright (c) 1997-2014 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2014 Zend Technologies
with Xdebug v2.2.5, Copyright (c) 2002-2014, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: It's usually advisable that constructors do as little work as possible, in fact if at all possible they shouldn't do anything other than assign their arguments to instance variables.  A simple constructor doesn't really need to be tested so its effect on the code coverage report shouldn't really matter.  As for your case, you could try simply having an empty setup() method and doing $this object = new ObjectUnderTest() in every test case.

Comment: @GordonM The only thing i want to test is, if the typehinting for the dependencies (database, logger, ...) is set up correct. The __construct-method does assignments only.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since this question started to gain some momentum: Here is my kind-of-solution for the problem.

My **unit**-test (`FooTest`) of `Foo` will always **use** `Foo`, therefore I add `@uses Foo` to the class.

*This is also important if `protected`/`private` functions are used by `public` functions, because else you have to add each and every `protected`/`private` function to a test, if the class uses the function internally. I even think it is wrong if you are doing unit-tests, because a unit-test must not care about how the class does "stuff", it should only assert that a specific input results in a specific output.*

*(Additionally: The constructor should only do assignments, nothing else.)*

After adding `@uses` the error will disapear.

(You can add `@covers Foo::_construct` to the class to have code-coverage of your constructor.)

```
/**
 * @uses Foo 
 * (optional)@covers Foo::__construct
 */
class FooTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $_foo;

    protected function setUp()
    {
        $this->_foo=new Foo(10);
    }

    public function testGetBar()
    {
        $this->assertSame(10, $this->_foo->getBar());
    }

    /**
     * @covers Foo::getBar2
     */
    public function testGetBar2()
    {
        $this->assertSame(10, $this->_foo->getBar2());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have specified strict coverage with `checkForUnintentionallyCoveredCode="true"`. And since [PHPUnit 4.0](http://thephp.cc/news/2014/03/phpunit-4-0-code-coverage-improvements) PHPUnit has the following behaviour:

> **Dealing with unintentionally covered code**
>
> PHPUnit 4.0 can optionally be strict about unintentionally covered code (strict > coverage mode). When enabled, PHPUnit will fail a test that uses the @covers annotation and executes code that is not specified using a @covers annotation.

Comment: I am fully aware of that. The problem is: The test does not execute `__construct`, only the `setUp` does, nevertheless I have to specify `@covers` for `__construct` on every test, else the test is classified as _risky_.

Comment: setUp() and teardown() are executed for every test, so aren't they part of the test in that sense? I haven't tested it, but I expect that if I use the @expectedException annotation and throw that exception in my setup() or teardown(), the test will pass because of that....

Answer (score 1):

On **PHPUnit >= 6.0** set beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation to false on `phpunit.xml`:

```
<phpunit
     // ....     
     beStrictAboutCoversAnnotation="false"
>
// ....
```

Also, you can run phpunit without --strict-coverage

More info on [Risky Tests: Unintentionally Covered Code](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/risky-tests.html)